# Running FFMPEG multithreads in a SLURM environment

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg, encoding, multiprocessing, slurm

I am interested in speeding up my encoding of an mp4 file from thousands of jpegs. my launch command is the following

```
singularity exec --bind $work_dir:/mnt $work_dir/container.sif ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in /mnt/processed_images/$image_folder/image-%06d.jpeg; do echo "file '$f'";done) -vf "crop=trunc(iw/3)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -movflags +faststart /mnt/processed_images/summary_files/${image_folder}.mp4
```

So I have a lot of images so I had to jump through hoops to pipe them into ffmpeg. I do not really do any tweaking of the encoder actually. I am not even sure what encoder I am using since I do not specify (I think). I am on a distributed computing environment but I do not leverage it at all. A job takes roughly 8 hours to complete which is not ideal. I have access to lots of memory and cores in theory but I am not sure how to tap that power.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Did you consider splitting the task? You could create for example 4 four sub movies, submit them in different jobs and the concatenate them in the end. How many cores are you using at the moment? On my local machine ffmpeg uses multiple cores by default.

Comment: @nameiki I am not sure I would assume 1 core or thread since it takes forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use multiple cores on a slurm machine it is easiest to use submit scripts and then submitting the job. If the following file is called submit.sh then the submit command would be `sbatch submit.sh`. The script would request 20 cores and 50 GB of memory for 24 hours. You will probably have to add some slurm options in the beginning of the script that are cluster specific.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20
#SBATCH --mem=50GB

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

srun singularity exec --bind $work_dir:/mnt $work_dir/container.sif ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in /mnt/processed_images/$image_folder/image-%06d.jpeg; do echo "file '$f'";done) -vf "crop=trunc(iw/3)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -movflags +faststart /mnt/processed_images/summary_files/${image_folder}.mp4
```

Comment: I think this could help but I am not sure how I would know the order of the sub movies. I have over 100K frames so I would not want to have manually check the submovies to put them in order. Do you have a way of submitting sublists or something so I would go from 100K frames to 100 movies?